# Ensure button is click

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have a button (type = "radio"), and this button has Javascript on it.
I located the button using xpath:

```
browser.element(:xpath, n2).wait_until_present  
browser.element(:xpath, n2).fire_event "onclick"
```

Let's say I have to click the same button for 100 times in a loop, and 80% of the time it's failing.  It works some times without any problem.  After I click the button and when I moved down the browser doing other clicks, this button is un-clicking (clear) by itself.
I need this button to stay clicked all the times while I am on that page.

I try adding delays, but no help.  Is there any other way to handle this issue.

Comment: Either point us to a page where the problem can be reproduced or create a page and put it somewhere public, like dropbox.

Comment: Just so you know nomenclature wise.  a Button is one type of HTML Input element, and it's also easy to have link items that appear (via an image file) as a button.  A Radio is a completely different type of input control, designed to allow you to pick only one choice out of many

Comment: Please show us the relevant portion of the HTML

Answer (score 2):

Watir provides specific methods for interacting with radio-button type input elements, see http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Radio

Don't use xpath as a locator unless you have no other choice, its ugly, brittle if not done right, and hard to make sense of.  For a radio element you usually identify by the value, or text

--Using the example at http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

To set the Cheese radio

```
browser.radio(:value => "Cheese").set
```

To examine it's state use .set? it will return true of false

```
puts browser.radio(:value => "Cheese").set?
```

be aware that if there is javascript on the page, depending on what actions it takes, it could unset the radio. But you could always have your script check it's state after you have taken other actions on that page.